# What is the meaning of the statement in Genesis 4:26 stating then began men to call upon the name of YHWH?

Tags: exegesis, old-testament, genesis

There is little consensus in commentaries as to the meaning of that phrase in Genesis chapter 4.

Genesis 4:26  NRKJV

> 26 And to Seth, to him also there was born a son; and he called his name Enos: then began men to call upon the name of יהוה.

How is this covered in Baptist Bible College?

Comment: `There is little consensus` ... `Is there a general agreement...?`.  You answered your question before you even asked it. What kind of answer do you want from us?

Comment: @ Flimzy Commentators are only a small portion of Bible scholars. There are many other Bible scholars such as professors at Bible colleges and other Universities where Theology is taught. Not having the advantage of having attended any of these I am not well versed on the multitude of opinions on these subjects, and what I want from you is what have you learned in your studies especially those of you who have gone to these institutes of higher learning.

Comment: I think it's pretty safe to say that commentaries offer a very representative view of scholars. Respected commentaries always come from people who know the material well--that is, scholars.

Comment: And as a general rule, a theme I see repeated in your questions, "What do Bible Scholars say on this?" is not a good fit for this site. There are Bible Scholars who vehemently disagree with each other on very important issues. Your questions need to be much more specific about which viewpoint you're looking for.

Comment: @ Flimzy Point well taken I will keep that in mind for future questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some Bible commentaries available on this verse. Read them [here at BibleHub.com for commentaries on Genesis 4:26](http://biblehub.com/genesis/4-26.htm). There are three available - Matthew Henry, Gill and Jamieson-Fausset.

The best one I find is *Gill's Exposition of the Entire Bible*. It says (excerpt) -

> then began men to call upon the name of the Lord; not but that Adam
>   and Abel, and all good men, had called upon the name of the Lord, and
>   prayed to him, or worshipped him before this time personally, and in
>   their families; but now the families of good men being larger, and
>   more numerous, **they joined together in social and public worship**: or
>   since it may be thought there were public assemblies for religious
>   worship before this time, **though it may be they had been neglected,
>   and now were revived with more zeal and vigour; seeing the Cainites
>   incorporating themselves, and joining families together, and building
>   cities, and carrying on their civil and religious affairs among
>   themselves, they also formed themselves into distinct bodies; and not
>   only separated from them, but called themselves by a different name;
>   for so the words may be rendered: "then began men to call themselves",
>   or "to be called by the name of the Lord" ; the sons of God, as
>   distinct from the sons of men; which distinction may be observed in
>   Genesis 6:2** and has been retained more or less ever since: some choose
>   to translate the words, "then began men to call in the name of the
>   Lord" ; that is, to call upon God in the name of the Messiah, the
>   Mediator between God and man; having now, since the birth of Seth, and
>   especially of Enos, clearer notions of the promised seed, and of the
>   use of him, and his name, in their addresses to God; see John 14:13

In short, Gill is saying that, from the time of Enosh, the descendants of Adam are now worshiping God together and called themselves *"sons of God"*; while the descendants of Cain are called *"sons of men"*, who lived separately and busy around building cities. Read the same verse in New Living Translation -

> When Seth grew up, he had a son and named him Enosh. At that time
>   people first began to **worship** the LORD by name. (Genesis 6:2, NLV)

Comment: @ Mawia Thank you, I have those commentaries along with Guzik, Hole, and several others in my study program, but I was wondering more about how it was handled in Academia than anything.